# Get key code with javascript input event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to grab the input from keyboard and put it in a div. I also want to grab copy pasted string from the editor. So I am using **input event** instead of **keyup**.

To do this I need to grab the char code and convert it to a string. But I found that **e.which** won't work with input (at least not working with me, not quite sure about others). **It is returning 0 everytime**.

I want to keep the **"input"** event. So how do I get the key code for this event?

```js
var editor=document.getElementById('editor');
var content=document.getElementById('content');

editor.addEventListener('input',function(e){
    alert(e.which);
});
```

```css
#editor{
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid black;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding-left:4px;
    padding-right:4px;
    padding-bottom:1em;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id='editor' contenteditable='true' ></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) is not a [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) and [Event.which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) is a property of KeyboardEvent.

So if you want to get `e.which` then you need to use one of the available keyboard events like keypress, keyup or keydown

Comment: input let me get copy paste string.Thats why i intend to use it.Any other workarounds for that ?

Comment: @AL-zami you need to use 2 different handlers in that case... use key events to check `e.which` and `input` event for `copy/paste`

Comment: ok..if i put both of the event. .. is it possible that both of them will get triggered at the same time..if so,how i can prevent this?